# Issue with Pickling in Top2Vec v1.0.34

Tags: python, pickle, top2vec

I recently upgraded to Top2Vec version 1.0.34 and encountered an issue with pickling the model.
Specifically, I'm getting following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 8
      2 model_name_out = os.path.join(
      3                 stt.DATA_PATH_RESULTS,
      4                 f"{PROJECT_NAME}.pickle")
      7 with open(model_name_out, "wb") as file:
----> 8     pickle.dump(data, file)

AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject'
```

Here all the information:

```
Python version: 3.9.12
Top2Vec version: 1.0.34
```

Question:
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Are there any workarounds or known fixes for this problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The [usage documentation](https://github.com/ddangelov/Top2Vec#usage) says you should just call `.save()` and not pickle things by hand.

Comment: @AKX well I wanted to save the model and  the dataset together, and it was working, but after updating some packages brock up

Comment: Well, then you'd probably need to tell us what `data` is...

Comment: @AKX the dataset, that we trained the model, (pandas dataframe)

Comment: If it's just a dataframe, surely it can be pickled? How does `Top2Vec` relate to that?

Comment: @AKX because it complaining about top2vec. in this code : ```data = {
    "model": model,
    "dataset": reduced_df
}

```
if I remove the model and add anything else it is working. it was working as well with top2vec older version. but after upgrading, it brock up

Comment: Right, so you weren't speaking the truth when you said `data` was just a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at what [`model.save()` does](https://github.com/ddangelov/Top2Vec/blob/7403993804e241b3dc30bf489165dd4910689e55/top2vec/Top2Vec.py#L724-L773), it cleans up some things before pickling the instance to the given destination with `joblib.dump`, then restores them.

You should thus be able to

```
bio = io.BytesIO()
model.save(bio)
data = {"model_serialized": model, "dataset": reduced_df}
# ...
pickle.dump(data, file)
```

and to restore things from such a pickled dict,

```
data = pickle.load(file)
model = Top2Vec.load(io.BytesIO(data["model_serialized"])))
```